# VAR-aDCC full ARCH and GARCH parameter matrices in R

Tags: programming, garch

I am working with the `rmgarch` package in R and I estimated a VAR-aDCC model. Is there any way to extract the extended version of estimates (allowing for volatility spillovers)? More specific, I want the full ARCH and GARCH parameter matrices from the `dccfit` function of the `garch` package. I saw that in the `ccgarch` package there is this option, but the `dcc` package does not support the aDCC model.

Is this option available in the `rmgarch` package?

Comment: `garch` package and `dcc` package? Are you sure?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can model spillovers with the DCC model. Unlike BEKK, in DCC the conditional variance of each asset depends only on its own past, not on the past of other assets' conditional variances. Thus no spillovers.

Comment: That was also my point of view. But reading the following presentation I got a bit confused. https://www.r-project.org/conferences/useR-2008/slides/Nakatani.pdf

Comment: @KonstantinosGk,  Extended specification of the $h_t$ matrix as in *Extended* CCC (ECCC) might make volatility spillovers possible. However, DCC uses diagonal specification of the $h_t$ matrix (not extended), thus no spillovers.

Comment: the EDDC (Extended DCC) in what does it refer?

Comment: @KonstantinosGk, I do not understand your question.